# Задачка на PHP

Tags: php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formtest</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <form name="cucak" method="post" action="action.php">
                Name:<br>
                <input name="name" type="text" size="25"><br>
                Surname:<br>
                <input name="surname" type="text" size="25"><br>
                Email:<br>
                <input name="email" type="text" size="25"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Ok">
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Помогите написать программу action.php, и сделать так, чтобы введённые данные добавлялись в таблицу

Comment: Дайте хоть структуру таблицы что ли. И что уже пытались делать.

Comment: Да ничего он не пытался. Даже на сайт translit.ru зайти. =)

Comment: table name="cucak" , привет земляк )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы таблица могла добавляться до бессконечности и при этом "не пропадало" нужно юзать либо сессию либо куки либо хранилище данных.
т.е. например уже добавилось 1 значение в табличку, у нас уже лежит, например, $_SESSION['table'][0] то мы в самой отрисовке делаем примерно так

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
    </tr>
    <?foreach($_SESSION['table'] as $row):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?$row['name']?></td>
        <td><?$row['email']?></td>
    </tr>
    <?endforeach;?>
</table>
```

PS: Готовый код не писал(смотрим время поста :D), но думаю идея ясна.

`<form target="_blank">` в новой вкладке
а вот чтобы в новом окне без JS танцев с бубном у костра не обойтись :)

Comment: У меня эту роль исполняет скрытое поле.

Comment: но ИМХО лучше всетаки в куках или в сессии :)

Comment: Лучше в базе данных. =.= Но это мелочи

Comment: а как можно делать так, чтобы результат открылся в новом окне??

Comment: спасибо уже получилось, остался только данные в таблицу добажить, и ж список

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$table = array();
if(isset($_POST['table'])){
    $table64 = base64_decode($_POST['table']);
    $table = unserialize($table64);
}

$vars = array('name','surname','email');
$row = array();
foreach($vars as $var){
    if(!empty($_POST[$var])){
        $row[$var] = $_POST[$var];
    }else{
        $row[$var] = 'N/A';
    }
}
if($row['name']!='N/A' || $row['surname']!='N/A' || $row['email']!='N/A'){
    $table[] = $row;
}
$table64 = serialize($table);
$table64 = base64_encode($table64);

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formtest</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <form name="cucak" method="post" action="action.php">
                Name:<br>
                <input name="name" type="text" size="25"><br>
                Surname:<br>
                <input name="surname" type="text" size="25"><br>
                Email:<br>
                <input name="email" type="text" size="25"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Ok">
                <input type="hidden" name='table' value="<?=$table64?>" />
            </form>
        </body>
<?php if(isset($table)){?>
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>Email</td></tr>
<?php
foreach($table as $row){
    printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>",$row['name'],$row['surname'],$row['email']);
}
?>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Спосибо, но когда добожляю второю тройку, то первая удаляется и вместо него пишется вторая

Comment: У меня работает.  
Скрипт работает, пока вы заполняете тройки и жмете ОК. При обновлении страницы все пропадет: данные хранятся в hidden-поле.
Какой браузер?

Comment: opera 11,у меня работает, но жторою тройку не добовляет под первым, а добовляет вместо него

Answer (score 0):

В новом окне

```
<form name="cucak" action="action.php" method="post" target="foo" onsubmit="window.open('', 'foo', '')">
```